# configuration changes in Tridion inorder to interact with active directory

Tags: active-directory, tridion

- Can SDL Tridion, by default, talk to the active directory based on the domain of the server where Tridion is installed?
  o   Ex: we install tridion in the server server1.abc.com where abc.com is my domain
- If it cannot be done by default, can you please let me know how we can configure it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821075/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it can be done - this is the default behavior.

In the Add User dialog you should be able to type a domain name, and if the server (and the server's user account, MTSUser by default) is allowed to talk to that domain you'll get a list of the users and you can add them to the list of allowed Tridion users.

Nothing to configure unless you want LDAP integration.